# Arrays: Left Rotation in C

Tags: c, arrays, rotation

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation

A left rotation operation on an array of size n shifts each of the array's elements   1 unit to the left. For example, if 2 left rotations are performed on array [1,2,3,4,5] , then the array would become [3,4,5,1,2]

Perform k number of rotations and print.

Here's what I got so far but it only goes through one interaction, don't see what I am doing wrong

```
int main(){
   int n; //size
   int k; //number of rotations
   int a_i; //index
   scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
   int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n); //input array
   for(a_i = 0; a_i <= n; a_i++){
      scanf("%d",&a[a_i]);
   }

int temp;
for(a_i = 0; a_i <= k; a_i++){
    temp = a[0];
    for(a_i = 0; a_i < n-1; a_i++) {
        a[a_i] = a[a_i+1];
    }
    a[a_i] = temp;   
}

for(a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
    printf("%d ", a[a_i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since the only thing that matters is the output from the program, you don't even need to rotate the contents of the array. Just print from `k` to `n-1`, and then print from `0` to `k-1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array with `n` elements then the valid range of indices to access elements of the array is `[0, n-1]`.

Thus the loops in your program in most cases use invalid ranges of indices.

Also you are using the same variable `a_i` for two nested loops that will give incorrect index for the outer loop

```
for(a_i = 0; a_i <= k; a_i++){
    temp = a[0];
    for(a_i = 0; a_i < n-1; a_i++) {
        a[a_i] = a[a_i+1];
    }
    a[a_i] = temp;   
}
```

Also this statement

```
for(a_i = 0; a_i <= k; a_i++){
```

sets `k + 1` iterations instead of `k` iterations.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why can't I use the same index for both loops, it references the same array

Comment: @qazwsx123 In the outer loop the index should be changed from like 0, 1 and so on/  However after executing the inner loop you will not get that the next value of the index for the outer loop was increased by one.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop be like that

```
   for(a_i=0; a_i<k; a_i++)
{

    int temp=a[0];
        for(a_j=0; a_j<n-1; a_j++)
        {
        a[a_j] = a[a_j+1];
         }
    a[n-1] = temp;

   }
   for(a_i=0 ; a_i<n ; a_i++)
   {

    printf("%d ",a[a_i]);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code for for rotating array to left by d times
i things this one help you!!**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Bilakhiya
 */
public class LeftRotate {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static ArrayList<Integer> leftarray(ArrayList<Integer>A1,int n,int d)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
        {
           leftby1(A1,n);

        }
        return A1;
    }
    static ArrayList<Integer> leftby1(ArrayList<Integer>A1,int n)
    {
        int i,temp;
        temp=A1.get(0);
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            A1.set(i,A1.get(i+1) );
        }
        A1.set(i,temp);
        return A1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
      ArrayList<Integer> A=new ArrayList<>();
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      int n=sc.nextInt();
      int d=sc.nextInt();
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          A.add(sc.nextInt());
      } 
      ArrayList<Integer> B=leftarray(A,n,d);
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          System.out.print(B.get(i)+" ");
      }      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
int i, result[a_count]; //i --> index
// a_count --> len of array 'a'

for(i=0;i<a_count;i++){//d --> number of shifts/characters_to_skip 

    result[i]=a[(i+d)%a_count];  //Rotate and save the rotational values in new array

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arrSize = in.nextInt();
        int rotation = in.nextInt();


        int arr[] = new int[arrSize];

        for(int arr_i=0; arr_i < arrSize; arr_i++){
            arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        int temp = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < rotation; i++){
            temp=arr[0];
            for(int j = 0; j < arrSize-1; j++){
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];        
            }
            arr[arrSize-1] = temp;

        }

         for(int arr_i=0; arr_i < arrSize; arr_i++){
            System.out.println(arr[arr_i]);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is C question. This is not C answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
class Solution
{

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string[] tokens_n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[0]);
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[1]);
        string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(a_temp, Int32.Parse);
        int num = 0;
        int length = a.Length;
        int templength = length - (n - k);
        Console.WriteLine(a[templength]);
        num = templength + 1;
        if (num >= length)
            num = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a[num]);
            num = num + 1;
            if (num >= length)
                num = 0;

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is C question. This is not C answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,j,arr[100000],n,d;
scanf("%d\t%d",&n,&d);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
for(i=0;i<d;i++)
{ 
    int first=arr[0];
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        arr[j]=arr[j+1];
    }
    arr[n-1]=first;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
}
    return 0;
}
```